# Detect the presence of mouse, keyboard, monitor on Windows with Visual C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, winapi, visual-c++

I am looking to write a basic function to detect the presence of devices in the system (Windows, with Visual C++), an example on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363215(v=vs.85).aspx
shows how to detect when a CD or DVD is inserted or not, Even if I found out the WM_DEVICECHANGE for the mouse, keyboard and monitor... still this message is only sent to the application when a change takes place, my program may start on a PC when the mouse is not connected and WM_DEVICECHANGE will be sent, i need to detect that.
Another good sample here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14500/Detecting-Hardware-Insertion-and-or-Removal
but only detects USB devices, my system is supposed to work on very old PCs with PS2 keyboard and parallel printers...
Any suggestions, ideas would be highly appreciated

Comment: There's no notification sent for a PS2 keyboard or mouse, because they're not hot-swappable. (You're supposed to power down the computer before connecting/disconnecting them.) If they aren't supposed to be changed while the computer is operating, there's no message sent when they are. (It's like expecting to get a Windows message when someone pulls the power cord from the wall socket - by the time the message could get sent, it's too late and you're screwed anyway.)

Comment: IMO easiest way is WMI. You have complete device list and it's ready to use (and observable without polling). Alternative may be registry but...

Comment: yes unpluggin a PS2 mouse won't send a message but there is a change in status somewhere that can be detected, mouse is not present, just like unplugging and old parallel printer, the status changes from ready to not

Comment: Look at `GetSystemMetrics(SM_MOUSEPRESENT)` and the [Raw Input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536.aspx) API.